# How to show that $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(k+1)x - \cos kx}{k}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

How to show that $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(k+1)x - \cos kx}{k}$ converges?

My solution: I tried to use Cauchy convergence theorem. For any $\epsilon>0$, I need to find $N$ such that for all $n \geq m \geq N$, the inequality 
$$ 
\left| \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{\cos(k+1)x - \cos kx}{k} \right|<\epsilon 
$$
holds.
We have
$$ 
\left| \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{\cos(k+1)x - \cos kx}{k} \right|\\
 =\left| -2\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{\sin(\frac{k}{2}+1)x \sin \frac{1}{2}x}{k} \right| \\
\leq \left| -2\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \right|\\
= \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}.
$$
But I am not it seems that only when $n$ is close to $m$, $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ is small.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convergence is trivially implied by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), since
$$ a_k = \cos((k+1)x)-\cos(kx) $$
is a sequence with bounded partial sums,
$$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\right| = \left|\cos((n+1)x)-\cos(x)\right|\leq 2 $$
and $b_k=\frac{1}{k}$ is a sequence decreasing to zero, hence $\sum_{k\geq 1}a_k b_k$ is converging.

---

By writing $\cos z$ as $\text{Re}(e^{iz})$ you may also check that
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos((k+1)x)-\cos(kx)}{k} $$
is an even, $2\pi$-periodic function whose value for $x\in(0,\pi)$ is given by:
$$ (1-\cos x)\log\left(2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{x-\pi}{2}\sin(x), $$
so that:
$$ \left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos((k+1)x)-\cos(kx)}{k}\right|\leq \log 4. $$