# How to show that $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(k+1)x - \cos kx}{k}$ converges using Cauchy convergence theorem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof, cauchy-sequences

I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515429/how-to-show-that-x-n-sum-k-1n-frac-cosk1x-cos-kxk-converges). It is solved by using Dirichlet's test.

Is it possible to show that $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\cos(k+1)x - \cos kx}{k}$ converges using Cauchy convergence theorem? Thank you very much.

Comment: "Cauchy convergence theorem" is "a sequence is convergent if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence"?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write:

$$\frac{\cos(k+1)x-\cos(kx)}{k}=\frac{\cos((k+1)x)}{k+1}-\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}+\frac{\cos((k+1)x)}{k(k+1)}$$
Then if $n\geq m$
$$\sum_{k=m}^n \left(\frac{\cos((k+1)x)-\cos(kx)}{k}\right)=\frac{\cos((n+1)x)}{n+1}-\frac{\cos(mx)}{m}+\sum_{m}^n\frac{\cos((k+1)x)}{k(k+1)}$$

We have
$$\left|\frac{\cos((n+1)x)}{n+1}-\frac{\cos(mx)}{m}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{m}$$
and
$$\left|\sum_m^n\frac{\cos((k+1)x)}{k(k+1)}\right|\leq \sum_{m}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Hence
$$\left|\sum_{k=m}^n \left(\frac{\cos(k+1)x-\cos(kx)}{k}\right)\right|\leq \frac{2}{m}$$
and it is easy to finish.

Comment: @kamilo9875: Thank you for editing.